# How do you declare n consecutive variables using a scanner and while loop?

Tags: java

```
    package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(sc != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("first number: ");
            int firstNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("second number: ");
            int secondNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));
        }
    }
}
```

So my intended goal is to have a script that will allow me to add two integers (chosen by user input with a scanner) and once those two are added i can then start a new sum. I'd also like to break from my while loop when the user inputs 0.

I think my error is that i can't use the != operator on the Scanner type Could someone explain the flaw in my code? (I'm used to python which is probably why I'm making this mistake)

Comment: Java is indeed not Python. You can't compare a `Scanner` to an integer. The question is: what exactly is it that you want to achieve with that comparison? A `Scanner` itself cannot be zero, instead, the Scanner *does* something of which the *result* could be zero.

Comment: Like @MCEmperor said, you can't compare `Scanner` object with an `Integer`. Probably you wanted to compare the input values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable out of while scope and update it until condition is not met

Try this:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int firstNum = 1;
        int secondNum = 1;

        while(firstNum !=0 && secondNum != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("first number: ");
            firstNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("second number: ");
            secondNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have some kind of an "infinite" loop like so:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("first number: ");
            int firstNum = sc.nextInt();
            if (firstNum == 0) {
              break;
            }

            System.out.println("second number: ");
            int secondNum = sc.nextInt();
            if (secondNum == 0) {
              break;
            }

            System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just remove the while block since it has no sence to use it

Here the corrected code

```
 package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("first number: ");
            int firstNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("second number: ");
            int secondNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));

    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the while is that i want the script to run over and over again unless the user inputs 0. This would result in the script running only once. sorry if i wasn't clear enough

Comment: ah ok wait a minute

Comment: look at my second post

Comment: did you see my two posts?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the Object sc with an integer value 0. You can do the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
             System.out.println("first number: ");
             int firstNum = sc.nextInt();
             while(firstNum != 0)
             {

                 System.out.println("second number: ");
                 int secondNum = sc.nextInt();

                 System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));

                 System.out.println("first number: ");
                 firstNum = sc.nextInt(); 
             }
         }
    }
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

             while(true)
             {
                 System.out.println("first number: ");
                 int firstNum = sc.nextInt();
                 if(firstNum == 0) {
                     break;
                 }
                 System.out.println("second number: ");
                 int secondNum = sc.nextInt();

                 System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));

                 System.out.println("first number: ");
                 firstNum = sc.nextInt(); 
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly af but it will let you understand the process

```
 package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean continueRunning = true;
        while (continueRunning) {
            System.out.println("first number: ");
            int firstNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("second number: ");
            int secondNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));
            continueRunning = firstNum != 0 && secondNum != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also ugly but i will sleep better tonight.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        requestNumbersAndSum(scanner);
    }

    private static void requestNumbersAndSum(Scanner scanner) {
        int firstNum = requestANum(scanner, "first number: ");
        int secondNum = requestANum(scanner, "second number: ");
        System.out.println("The  sum of your numbers: " + (firstNum + secondNum));
        requestNumbersAndSum(scanner);
    }

    private static int requestANum(Scanner scanner, String messageToUser) {
        System.out.println(messageToUser);
        int requestedNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        if(requestedNumber == 0){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return requestedNumber;
    }
}
```